# Laravel -- Flatten data appended via `with`

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've got two models, `User` and `Seminar`. In English, the basic idea is that a bunch of users attend any number of seminars. Additionally, exactly one user may volunteer to speak at each of the seminars.

My implementation consists of a `users` table, a `seminars` table, and a `seminar_user` pivot table.

The `seminar_user` table has a structure like this:

```
 seminar_id  |  user_id  | speaking
-------------|-----------|---------
     int     |    int    |  bool
```

The relationships are defined as follows:

```
/** On the Seminar model */
public function members()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

/** On the User model */
public function seminars()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Seminar::class);
}
```

I am struggling to figure out how to set up a "relationship" which will help me get a Seminar's speaker. I have currently defined a method like this:

```
public function speaker()
{
    return $this->members()->where('speaking', true);
}
```

The reason I'd like this is because ultimately, I'd like my API call to look something like this:

```
public function index()
{
    return Seminar::active()
        ->with(['speaker' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('name');
        }])
        ->get()
        ->toJson();
}
```

The problem is that since the `members` relationship is actually a `belongsToMany`, even though I know there is only to ever be a single `User` where `speaking` is true, an array of `User`'s will always be returned.

One workaround would be to post-format the response before sending it off, by first setting a temp `$seminars` variable, then going through a `foreach` and setting each `$seminar['speaker'] = $seminar['speaker'][0]` but that really stinks and I feel like there should be a way to achieve this through Eloquent itself.

**How can I flatten the data that is added via the `with` call? (Or rewrite my relationship methods)**

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `speaker` function to this

```
public function speaker()
{
    return $this->members()->where('speaking', true)->first();
}
```

This will always give you an Item as opposed to a Collection that you currently receive.

Comment: This will not let you play with the query, and won't let you use `with` to eager-load it as a relationship in the model.

Comment: @JosephSilber May be... but this will solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Thanks @JosephSilber... This is precisely why I haven't adopted this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new relation on `Seminar` model as:

```
public function speaker()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->wherePivot('speaking', true);
}
```

And your query will be as:

```
Seminar::active()
    ->with(['speaker' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('name');
    }])
    ->get()
    ->toJson();
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) scroll down to `Filtering Relationships Via Intermediate Table Columns`

Comment: Effectively, the only difference between this code and what I currently have is you have changed `where` to `wherePivot`. In this case it returns the exact same thing and thus your solution yields the same result as I already have. :(

Comment: The difference is also of `$this->belongsToMany()`. Have you tried it?

Comment: Actually, I am calling the `members` function which returns the same `belongsToMany`, so that is why i said it is the same. Either way, yes I have tried it. The issue remains that `belongsToMany` assumes multiple values may be fetched so it returns an array of objects, even if only one value is present.